# How to count the number of observations in R like Stata command count

Tags: r, stata

```
aaa<- data.frame(sex=c(1,1,2,2,1,1), group1=c(1,2,1,2,2,2),group2=c("A","B","A","B","A","B"))
```

stata command:

```
count if sex==1 & group1==2
count if sex==1 & group2=="A"
```

count counts the number of observations that satisfy the specified conditions. If no conditions are specified, count displays the number of observations in the data.

How to count in R? Thank you.

Comment: Here is a reasonable dictionary mapping [`stata commands to r`](https://github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/RStata/blob/master/dictionary.md)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `with` function will let you use shorthand column references and `sum` will count `TRUE` results from the expression(s).

```
sum(with(aaa, sex==1 & group1==2))
## [1] 3

sum(with(aaa, sex==1 & group2=="A"))
## [1] 2
```

As @[mnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385941/mnel) pointed out, you can also do:

```
nrow(aaa[aaa$sex==1 & aaa$group1==2,])
## [1] 3

nrow(aaa[aaa$sex==1 & aaa$group2=="A",])
## [1] 2
```

The benefit of that is that you can do:

```
nrow(aaa)
## [1] 6
```

And, the behaviour matches Stata's `count` almost exactly (syntax notwithstanding).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the filter function from the dplyr package which returns rows with matching conditions.

```
> library(dplyr)

> nrow(filter(aaa, sex == 1 & group1 == 2))
[1] 3
> nrow(filter(aaa, sex == 1 & group2 == "A"))
[1] 2
```